# Install script is called when running the cases with webdriverIO & selenium-standalone service

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using the webdriverIO and selenium-standalone(chrome) for my test. But I got the following error every time. It seems the install script is called when running the cases, either selenium or chromedriver. But the selenium-standalone server and chrome driver had been installed. And I started it with `"java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar"`. Also the chromedriver is 2.34.

```
[li@localhost webdriverio-test]$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js
2019-04-22T14:55:20.490Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise wdio service "selenium-standalone"
2019-04-22T14:55:20.527Z INFO @wdio/cli:Launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2019-04-22T14:59:22.452Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Could not request headers from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_linux64.zip: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ljl/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/install.js:552:8)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/ljl/webdriverio-test/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
```

Continue...

another one:

```
2019-04-22T15:57:33.264Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Could not request headers from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ljl/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/install.js:552:8)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/ljl/webdriverio-test/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
```

Continue...

```
[li@localhost webdriverio-test]$ google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 73.0.3683.75 
[li@localhost webdriverio-test]$ chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d)



$ cat package.json 
{
    "name": "webdriverio-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "webdriverio": "^5.7.15"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.7.11",
      "@wdio/cli": "^5.7.15",
      "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.7.15",
      "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.7.14",
      "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.7.8"
   }
}
```

Why install script is called when running cases?

Comment: Did you find a solution? We encounter the same problems. Tests are running, but it always takes about 20 seconds until the TLS-Connection fails. We are behind a company proxy and there seems to be no option to start wdio with proxy settings